# Wrong usage of に？

Tags: particle-に

> みんなをレストランにさそう。

Here I want to invite everybody to the restaurant but I'm confused about the particles, don't people usually use "に"? Like "Person" にさそう.

Comment: When your question gets closed normally the thing to do is edit it with what people said about why it was closed in mind, not delete it and respost it exactly, unchanged.

Comment: The answer to your last question is no, we don't. The *person* is the direct object of さそう.

Comment: It's a different usage. Actions directed towards other people and things can be transitive and ditransitive, depending if we have only 1 or 2 related objects. If we talk about inviting, we invite someone somewhere. This is why you have both を and に.

Comment: @Angelo: already edited and other moderator suggested me to better create a new one with this content.